# replicating a sql function in sas datastep

Tags: sas, proc-sql, datastep

Hi another quick question

in proc sql we have **on** which is used for conditional join is there something similar for sas data step

for example

```
proc sql;
....
data1 left join data2
on first<value<last
quit;
```

can we replicate this in sas **datastep**

like

```
data work.combined
  set data1(in=a) data2(in=b)

   if a then output;
run;
```

Comment: Are the keys on table `data1` unique?

Comment: no the left join does not have a 1-1 match

Comment: @arcoder sorry - I rephrased the comment...

Comment: What tables are first/value/last coming from?

Comment: data1 contains first,last data2 contains value

Comment: And does that SQL produce the right results? You've got a potential many-many there - that's not practical to reproduce in a data step. (Unless you're doing a row by row value compare)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there is a simple (but subtle) way in just 7 lines of code.

What you intend to achieve is intrinsically a conditional Cartesian join which can be done by a do-looped set statement. The following code use the test dataset from Dmitry and a modified version of the code in the appendix of [SUGI Paper 249-30](http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/sugi30/249-30.pdf)

```
data data1;
    input first last;
datalines;
1 3
4 7
6 9
;
run;

data data2;
    input value;
datalines;
2
5
6
7
;
run;

/***** by data step looped SET *****/
DATA CART_data; 
    SET data1; 
    DO i=1 TO NN; /*NN can be referenced before set*/
        SET data2 point=i nobs=NN; /*point=i - random access*/
        if first<value<last then OUTPUT; /*conditional output*/
    END; 
RUN;

/***** by SQL *****/
proc sql;
    create table cart_SQL as 
    select * from data1 
    left join data2
        on first<value<last;
quit;
```

One can easily see that the results coincide.

Also note that from SAS 9.2 [documentation](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000173782.htm): "At compilation time, SAS reads the descriptor portion of each data set and assigns the value of the NOBS= variable automatically. Thus, you CAN refer to the NOBS= variable BEFORE the SET statement. The variable is available in the DATA step but is not added to any output data set."

Comment: Yeah I am also amazed when I learned that. Although I doubt the overhead of the do-loop random-accessing the physical location of data2.

Answer (score 1):

You can also can reproduce sql join in one DATA-step using hash objects. It can be really fast but depends on the size of RAM of your machine since this method loads one table into memory. So the more RAM  - the larger dataset you can wrap into hash. This method is particularly effective for look-ups in relatively small reference table.

```
data have1;
    input first last;
datalines;
1 3
4 7
6 9
;
run;

data have2;
    input value;
datalines;
2
5
6
7
;
run;

data want;
    if _N_=1 then do;
        if 0 then set have2;
        declare hash h(dataset:'have2');
        h.defineKey('value');
        h.defineData('value');
        h.defineDone();
        declare hiter hi('h');
    end;
    set have1;

    rc=hi.first();
    do while(rc=0);
        if first<value<last then output;
        rc=hi.next();
    end;
    drop rc;
run;
```

The result:

```
value  first  last
2       1       3
5       4       7
6       4       7
7       6       9
```

Comment: Why is the first row repeated at the end of the output dataset?

Comment: Oh, it's just a copy/pasting error, thanks for noticing. I'll edit the answer.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a direct way to do this with a MERGE.  This is one example where the SQL method is clearly superior to any SAS data step methods, as anything you do will take much more code and possibly more time.

However, depending on the data, it's possible a few approaches may make sense.  In particular, the format merge.

If `data1` is fairly small (even, say, millions of records), you can make a format out of it.  Like so:

```
data fmt_set;
set data1;
format label $8.;
start=first;  *set up the names correctly;
end=last;
label='MATCH';
fmtname='DATA1F';
output;
if _n_=1 then do; *put out a hlo='o' line which is for unmatched lines;
start=.; *both unnecessary but nice for clarity;
end=.;
label='NOMATCH';
hlo='o';
output;
end;
run;

proc format cntlin=fmt_set; *import the dataset;
quit;

data want;
set data2;
if put(value,DATA1F.)="MATCH";
run;
```

This is very fast to run, unless `data1` is extremely large (hundreds of millions of rows, on my system) - faster than a data step merge, if you include sort time, since this doesn't require a sort.  One major limitation is that this will only give you one row per `data2` row; if that is what is desired, then this will work.  If you want repeats of `data2` then you can't do it this way.

If `data1` may have overlapping rows (ie, two rows where start/end overlap each other), you also will need to address this, since start/end aren't allowed to overlap normally.  You can set `hlo="m"` for every row, and "om" for the non-match row, or you can resolve the overlaps.

I'd still do the sql join, however, since it's much shorter to code and much easier to read, unless you have performance issues, or it doesn't work the way you want it to.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution, using a temporary array to hold the lookup dataset. Performance is probably similar to Dmitry's hash-based solution, but this should also work for people still using versions of SAS prior to 9.1 (i.e. when hash objects were first introduced).

I've reused Dmitry's sample datasets:

```
data have1;
    input first last;
datalines;
1 3
4 7
6 9
;
run;

data have2;
    input value;
datalines;
2
5
6
7
;
run;

/*We need a macro var with the number of obs in the lookup dataset*/
/*This is so we can specify the dimension for the array to hold it*/
data _null_;
     if 0 then set have2 nobs = nobs;
     call symput('have2_nobs',put(nobs,8.));
     stop;
run;

 data want_temparray;
    array v{&have2_nobs} _temporary_;
    do _n_ = 1 to &have2_nobs;
        set have2 (rename=(value=value_array));
        v{_n_}=value_array;
    end;
    do _n_ = 1 by 1 until (eof_have1);
        set have1 end = eof_have1;
        value=.;
        do i=1 to &have2_nobs;
            if first < v{i} < last then do;
                value=v{i};
                output;
            end;
        end;
        if missing(value) then output;
    end;
    drop i value_array;
 run;
```

Output:

```
value  first  last
2       1       3
5       4       7
6       4       7
7       6       9
```

This matches the output from the equivalent SQL:

```
proc sql;
create table want_sql as 
    select * from
    have1 left join have2
    on first<value<last
    ;
quit;
run;
```